# Add scroll-y to a cell that overflows in jquer datatables and limit row height

Tags: django, scroll, datatables

I have a django web site that uses jquery datatables to display a table of 13 values. The first 12 values are a few words or numbers. The last column has many words. I would like to add a vertical scrollbar to the last column and limit the height of each row to 2 lines of text so the table is more compact.

For example, on a widescreen monitor the table looks ok.
[image]

But, if I make the browser window smaller, simulating a smaller screen, I get huge rows because of all the text in the last column.
[image]

I am open to suggestions on how to other suggestions on how to make the table look better on smaller screens, including cell phones.

The html for the table:

```
      {% for f in flights %}
  <div class="row mt-4">
    <div class="col-12">
      <div class="card mb-4">
        <div class="card-header pb-0">
          <p class="mb-1 pt-2 text-bold">{{ f.date }}</p>
          <h5 class="font-weight-bolder">{{ f.teacher_name }}</h5>
        </div>
        <div class="card-body px-0 pt-0 pb-2">
          <div class="table-responsive p-0">
            <table class="display" id="models" style="width:100%">
              <thead>
              <tr class="text-center mb-0 text-lg font-weight-bold">
                  <th rowspan="2">Rocket Name</th>
                  <th rowspan="2">Mission Specialists</th>
                  <th rowspan="2">Flight Engineers</th>
                  <th rowspan="2">Type</th>
                  <th colspan="1">Lift-off Weight</th>
                  <th colspan="2">Altitude</th>
                  <th rowspan="2">Egg</th>
                  <th rowspan="2">Shockcord</th>
                  <th rowspan="2">Nose cone</th>
                  <th rowspan="2">Coupler</th>
                  <th rowspan="2">Parachute</th>
                  <th rowspan="2">Notes</th>
              </tr>
                <tr class="text-center mb-0 text-lg font-weight-bold">
                  <th>grams</th>
                  <th>meters</th>
                  <th>feet</th>
                  </tr>
              </thead>
              <tbody>
              {%  for flight in f.flight_data %}
                <tr>
                  <td class="text-center mb-0 text-lg font-weight-bold text-nowrap">{{ flight.name }}</td>
                  <td class="text-center mb-0 text-lg font-weight-bold text-nowrap">{{ flight.mission_specialists }}</td>
                  <td class="text-center mb-0 text-lg font-weight-bold text-nowrap">{{ flight.flight_engineers }}</td>
                  <td class="text-center mb-0 text-lg font-weight-bold text-nowrap">{{ flight.rocket_type }}</td>
                  <td class="text-center mb-0 text-lg font-weight-bold text-nowrap">{{ flight.weight|format_zero|format_data:1|units:'g' }}</td>
                  <td class="text-center mb-0 text-lg font-weight-bold text-nowrap">{{ flight.altitude_m|format_zero|format_data:1|units:'m' }}</td>
                  <td class="text-center mb-0 text-lg font-weight-bold text-nowrap">{{ flight.altitude_f|format_zero|format_data:1|units:'ft' }}</td>
                  <td class="text-center mb-0 text-lg font-weight-bold text-nowrap">{{ flight.egg }}</td>
                  <td class="text-center mb-0 text-lg font-weight-bold text-nowrap">{{ flight.shockcord }}</td>
                  <td class="text-center mb-0 text-lg font-weight-bold text-nowrap">{{ flight.nose_cone }}</td>
                  <td class="text-center mb-0 text-lg font-weight-bold text-nowrap">{{ flight.coupler }}</td>
                  <td class="text-center mb-0 text-lg font-weight-bold text-nowrap">{{ flight.parachute }}</td>
                  <td class="mb-0 text-lg font-weight-bold">{{ flight.notes|safe }}</td>
                </tr>
              {% endfor %}    
              </tbody>
            </table>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: You could use `class='text-truncate' style='max-width: 150px;'` to limit the amount of text based on the screen size. Or you could make a button called `View notes` or something like that, that when pressed, shows a modal popup example: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/modal/#live-demo